# What component should hold the character movements in ecs and fsm?

Tags: java, libgdx, entity-system, state, fsm

In the below code, there's a FSM for `CharacterState` that will be handled also in `CharacterSystem`. The problem was, I don't know what component should hold movements data to process in `CharacterState` or `CharacterSystem`

```
public class CharacterState implements State<Entity> {
    STANDING,
    WALKING,
    RUNNING,
    IN_PAIN,
    DEAD
}

public enum Movements {
    STAND_STILL,
    MOVE_UP,
    MOVE_DOWN,
    MOVE_LEFT,
    MOVE_RIGHT,
    MOVE_UP_RIGHT,
    MOVE_UP_LEFT,
    MOVE_DOWN_RIGHT,
    MOVE_DOWN_LEFT;
}

CharacterComponent implements Component {
    Movements movement
}

MovementComponent implements Component {
    Movements movement
}

AnimationComponent implements Component {
    IntMap<Animation> map = new IntMap<Animation>();
}

animation.map.put(Movements.MOVE_UP.order, ASSET.CHAR_MOVE_UP);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new class just for holding the data if you are sure that the data belongs to multiple classes. Otherwise you can face [tight coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) issues.